# Downloading in several threads

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

As I'm located in China, using YouTube is a headache for me. I try to build a playlist downloader (I know about youtube-dl but want to learn smth new) and now it basically does its job. 
Because of unstable connections (vpn in China), in case of connection issues browser just stops downloading, but doesn't return control to my script. How can I handle this exception?
The whole file is here
[github link](https://github.com/belousov-mikhail/Netology/blob/master/Additional/youtube_downloader_v1.py)
Here's the code (downloading from the 3d party service):

```
def checkFileStatus(file_name):
"""Helper function for getDownloads, waits file to be downloaded"""
print('Ok, writing exactly ' + file_name)
checkFlag = False
while not checkFlag:
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        print(file_name + " exists")
        check_one = os.path.getsize(file_name)
        time.sleep(5)
        check_two = os.path.getsize(file_name)
        if check_two == check_one:
            checkFlag = True
            print(file_name + ' has been saved')
            return
    else:
        time.sleep(5)


def getDownloads(clip_links, home_dir):
    """Manages the whole downloading process
    - opens webdrive with Chrome
    - saves and renames files from valid links
    -  quits webdrive"""
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": home_dir}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    chromedriver = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe'
    savemediaurl = 'http://savemedia.com/'
    for index, entry in enumerate(clip_links):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
        saved_file = downloadFromSavemedia(savemediaurl, driver, entry[1], index+1)
        if saved_file:
            old_name = entry[0] + '.mp4'
            checkFileStatus(old_name)
            new_name = str(index+1).zfill(2) + '. ' + entry[0] + '.mp4'
            os.rename(old_name, new_name)
        driver.quit()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your downloads stop completely without returning control to your script, and you need a way to detect/handle this situation?

You could try mixing the [timeout-decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator/0.3.3) and [retry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry) packages:

```
from retry import retry
from timeout_decorator import timeout, TimeoutError

# <...>

@retry(TimeoutError, tries=3)
@timeout(300)  # Wait 300 seconds before raising the timeout exception
def _download(chromedriver, savemediaurl, entry, index):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    try:
        saved_file = downloadFromSavemedia(savemediaurl, driver, entry[1], index+1)
        if saved_file:
            old_name = entry[0] + '.mp4'
            checkFileStatus(old_name)
            new_name = str(index+1).zfill(2) + '. ' + entry[0] + '.mp4'
            os.rename(old_name, new_name)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

def getDownloads(clip_links, home_dir):
    """Manages the whole downloading process
    - opens webdrive with Chrome
    - saves and renames files from valid links
    -  quits webdrive"""
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": home_dir}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    chromedriver = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe'
    savemediaurl = 'http://savemedia.com/'
    for index, entry in enumerate(clip_links):
        _download(chromedriver, savemediaurl, entry, index)

    return
```

In the above, if the entire function call takes longer than 5 minutes, the timeout decorator throws a TimeoutError exception, which is then caught and handled by the retry decorator. This will repeat up to 3 times, after which the retry decorator will re-raise the TimeoutError.

Two things to note:

First, the timeout value will need to be tweaked by you. It's possible that the download could still be happening, but taking longer than expected, and the timeout decorator would still kill it.

Second, I have added a try/finally block to make sure the driver is closed gracefully if the timeout is thrown. Without this you will start to collect zombie chrome processes that will bog your system down.

(This is all untested)